# Get error on GML options

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to create wfs-t service I have used the ol.format.WFS#writeTransaction method and serialize the WFS-t XML  but my jslint always preview error at the GML format options. Is it possible that I am initializing the ol.format.WFS object incorrectly?

Or maybe I am passing the wrong options to the writeTransaction method? Or maybe it's a bug in OpenLayers4? this detail of my wfs-t service using angular http service:

```
private _transactWFS(feature: any, operation: any): any {

    let payload;

    try {
        const formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS({});
        const formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            featureNS: operation.featureNS,
            featureType: operation.featureType,
            srsName: operation.srsName
        });
        const xs = new XMLSerializer();
        let node: any = null;
        switch (operation.mode) {
            case 'insert':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([feature], null, null, formatGML);
                break;
            case 'update':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [feature], null, formatGML);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [feature], formatGML);
                break;
        }

        payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
    } catch (error) {}

    return payload;
}
```

lint message:

```
 [ts]
Argument of type 'GML' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WFSWriteTransactionOptions'.
Property 'featureNS' is missing in type 'GML'.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm give up using WFS Format for build WFS Transaction request so my problem was solved by myself, I found this lib [geojson-to-wfs-t-2](https://github.com/SKalt/geojson-to-wfs-t-2). This library is very legit for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenLayers WFS-T example](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/projection/examples/wfs-t.html):

```
        // Word to the Wise from an anonymous OpenLayers hacker:
        //             
        // The typename in the options list when adding/loading a wfs 
        // layer not should contain the namespace before, (as in the 
        // first typename parameter to the wfs consctructor).
        // 
        // Specifically, in the first parameter you write typename: 
        // 'topp:myLayerName', and in the following option list 
        // typeName: 'myLayerName'. 
        // 
        // If you have topp included in the second one you will get 
        // namespace 14 errors when trying to insert features.
        //
        wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.WFS(
            "Cities",
            "http://sigma.openplans.org/geoserver/wfs",
            {typename: 'topp:tasmania_cities'},
            {
                typename: "tasmania_cities",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp",
                extractAttributes: false,
                commitReport: function(str) {
                    OpenLayers.Console.log(str);
                }
            }
        );
```

Seems to indicate you are building your WFS object wrong.

Comment: Practically this error only shown up when I'm using typescript especially in GML format  options all attribute I assigned like featureNS always considered not assigned by writeTransactionOptions.